# c# - Google Sheets API v4 - Getting list of all sheets

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets-api

So at the moment I'm simply trying to get a list of all sheet names available in a google sheets. The sheet is a public sheet

The API key and spreadsheet id match what's online, but I'm getting back Error 400, bad request.

```
class GoogleAPI {
    static string ApplicationName = "Timetable";
    private static readonly String API_KEY = "AI**D0";
    static readonly string spreadsheetId = "1K**h8";

    public void getSheets()
    {
        var sheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            ApiKey = API_KEY,
            HttpClientFactory = new ProxySupportedHttpClientFactory(),
        });

        SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest request = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId);
        Data.Spreadsheet response = request.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
    }
}
```

The error from the console

> Exception thrown: 'Google.GoogleApiException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
> An exception of type 'Google.GoogleApiException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code.
> The request URL is invalid.

If I echo the details of the request as below

```
Debug.WriteLine("*********************************");
Debug.WriteLine(sheetsService.BaseUri);
Debug.WriteLine(request.RestPath);
Debug.WriteLine(request.SpreadsheetId);
Debug.WriteLine("***********************************");
```

I get

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/
v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}
19c3dGbBHhU7EtrCJBa7-bKMn7Jlg3R9xMXOP9HBZDPc
```

The url giving the correct response is

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/19c3dGbBHhU7EtrCJBa7-bKMn7Jlg3R9xMXOP9HBZDPc?key=AIzaSyDHBvpqlZ5MM04ZrsuGRzpPp_WDI7mS5D0

Comment: Has nothing to do with school homework, haven't been in school for over 10 years. Searching myself shows lots of ways to do it with OAuth, which results it the application wanting to login to google, i don't want that. On the Java version i could simply pass the API key instead of credentials which worked fine

Comment: I've also yet to find an example that shows how to do it with the API key rather than OAuth2